# Web Platform Installer: A newer version of IIS 8.0 Express was found on this machine

Tags: iis, iis-express, web-platform-installer

I am trying to install umbraco on my Windows 7 machine
I am running VS Ultimate 2013 v12 update 5 
When I attempt to use the Web Platform Installer to add Umbraco CMS, I get no joy:

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 175
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Fri, 11 Sep 2015 18:20:58 GMT
ETag: "7c78599bbeecd01:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=367
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: US
X-CID: 2

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1343597488.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID 5nine
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Security
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID 5nine
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Security
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Portal
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Portal
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Resource Provider
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Cruiser
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Showback
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Cruiser
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Showback
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Terawe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Fri, 18 Sep 2015 20:13:43 GMT
ETag: "7bcf8c844ef2d01:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=771
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: US
X-CID: 2

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer-97141593.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID MicrosoftAzure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/webapplicationlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor-97141593.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 May 2014 18:42:31 GMT
ETag: "26a51545ed6acf1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=396
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: US
X-CID: 2

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer-230948881.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/mediaproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor-230948881.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/ToolsProductList.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/ToolsProductList.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Feb 2015 17:50:31 GMT
ETag: "1a5deabc103fd01:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=14
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: US
X-CID: 2

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer-1135381691.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/ToolsProductList.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor-1135381691.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Content-Type: text/xml
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 May 2014 18:42:32 GMT
ETag: "8285645ed6acf1:0"
Cache-Control: max-age=803
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
X-CCC: US
X-CID: 2

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer-1877981721.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/5.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor-1877981721.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9842185' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\1343597488.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: Umbraco
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Umbraco CMS (Umbraco) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'Umbraco'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 203
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:27 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-Encoding header: 'gzip'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '23725'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '78834'
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Error getting last-modified header, error code: 12150
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : HttpQueryInfoWithRetry for HTTP_QUERY_LAST_MODIFIED failed.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product ASPNET45 does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product NetFxExtensibility45 does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product WebMatrix_appdetect does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product ASPNET45 does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product NetFxExtensibility45 does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product WebMatrix_appdetect does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product ASPNET45 does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product NetFxExtensibility45 does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product WebMatrix_appdetect does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'Umbraco'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4VS2010
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4VS2010_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WebMatrix
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'IISExpress8
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=259758&clcid=0x409' to: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp923.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=259758&clcid=0x409 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:55:42 GMT
Location: http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/3/163BBBDE-5523-416D-A293-EA0492020E4A/iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 231
Date: Sun, 20 Sep 2015 14:56:43 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '6635520'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '6635520'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\IISExpress8\5F4DD5BC67C54A2822C62EBEF8FFECCB37815E33\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp923.tmp' to: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\IISExpress8\5F4DD5BC67C54A2822C62EBEF8FFECCB37815E33\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/A/A/2AA5658E-7290-4DA0-89CB-06B3B6D59DCF/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi' to: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp10E1.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\IISExpress8\5F4DD5BC67C54A2822C62EBEF8FFECCB37815E33\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.msi', commandline: 'ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'IIS 8.0 Express - August 2012' is '1603'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'IIS 8.0 Express - August 2012' is Failure (A newer version of IIS 8.0 Express was found on this machine.)
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS 8.0 Express - August 2012 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : IIS 8.0 Express - August 2012 installation log: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2015-09-20T10.56.43\iisexpress_8_0_RTM_x64_en-US.txt
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '17952768'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '17952768'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebMatrix\93DA2A2F78142C8D0E01F438AECCFF7BDF320485\WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp10E1.tmp' to: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WebMatrix\93DA2A2F78142C8D0E01F438AECCFF7BDF320485\WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Microsoft WebMatrix 3'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F63CCD8-9288-4CC8-B58C-81D109F8F5A3/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' to: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp20BA.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft WebMatrix 3 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '37684848'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '37684848'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp20BA.tmp' to: C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Umbraco CMS'. Skipping download.
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Umbraco CMS had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 4
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\James.Fleming\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe /q /log C:\Users\JAMES~1.FLE\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4VS2010_Only_install.htm'. Process Id: 18744
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 5
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /C echo noop'. Process Id: 33332
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010)' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010)' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 (VS 2010) done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 5
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: IISExpress8, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:00.4960104
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WebMatrix, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: MVC4VS2010_Only, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:24.9769776
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: MVC4VS2010, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:00.1700034
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: Umbraco, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00

Answer (score 10):

Went to tools Uninstalled IIS Express 10.0

Re-ran set up

Sky parted

Comment: Sky parted also. :-)